# How can I fix problem with embeded sorting in vue-tables-2?

Tags: vue.js, vue-tables-2

I'm putting columns into sorting in first click it works and sorts But further there is this:Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
How can I fix it? 
Thanks in advance

```
Vue.use(VueTables.ClientTable);
new Vue({
    el: '#all-bio-scanner-component',
    data: {
        BC_URL: 'BC_ID=' + BC_ID,
        columns: ['scannerFirstName', 'amountCompletedTask', 'inOperation', 'lastReceive', 'scannerStatus', 'edit'],
        data: [],
        options: {
            perPage: 100,
            perPageValues: [100, 200],
            headings: {
                scannerFirstName: 'Имя',
                amountCompletedTask: 'Выполнено',
                inOperation: 'В работе',
                lastReceive: 'Последнее получено',
                edit: 'Дополнительное',
                scannerStatus: "Статус"
            },
            sortable: ['scannerFirstName', 'amountCompletedTask', 'inOperation', 'lastReceive', 'scannerStatus'],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/Prokat/40_Electroshit/scanners_info_get.php?BC_ID=' + BC_ID)
            .then(function (response) {
                storeBioScanners.commit(MUTATION_SET_BIO_SCANNERS, response.data);
                console.log(response)
            }).catch(function (error) {
            alert("Произошла ошибка:" + error);
        })
    },
    computed: {
        scanners() {
            return storeBioScanners.state.bioScanners;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        showBioScannerRedactor(bioScannerId) {
            storeBioScanners.commit(MUTATION_SET_EDITOR_BIO_SCANNERS_ID, bioScannerId);
        }
    }
})
;
```

Comment: If you can provide a CodePen or JSfiddle this will increase the chances to get help.

Comment: yes, sure https://jsfiddle.net/Leskhantos/jsd5fg7b/4/#&togetherjs=jstpa8zjrH

Comment: works like a charm = https://jsfiddle.net/cat72vzq/2/

Comment: yes works very well but here still error: vue.js:3149 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new Dep (vue.js:680)
    at defineReactive (vue.js:974)
    at Observer.walk (vue.js:900)
    at new Observer (vue.js:888)
    at observe (vue.js:956)
    at Object.reactiveSetter [as currentlySorting] (vue.js:1020)
    at VueComponent.proxySetter [as currentlySorting] (vue.js:3325)
    at VueComponent.t.exports (vue-tables-2.min.js:1)
    at VueComponent.sortingAlgorithm (vue-tables-2.min.js:1)
    at VueComponent.t.exports (vue-tables-2.min.js:1)